# How to join rows in csv file

Tags: python

I have a csv file with this format (1000 lines):

```
What, WP
makes, VBZ
them, PRP
do, VB
```

Its the word and the TAG , I want to join the tags to make the edges for a graph for example edges should be..

```
WP,VBZ
VBZ,PRP
PRP,VB
VB,PRP
```

and so on.. so far I manage to split only the tags in a list

```
files = glob.glob('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/nodos/*.csv')

  for path in files:
     dirname, filename = os.path.split(path)
     with open('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/nodos/%s' %filename) as 
     csvfile,open('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/aristas/%s' %filename,'w') as 
     output:   
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:          
         output.write(row[1])                   
         output.write('\n')
```

with that I get

```
WP
VBZ
PRP
VB
...
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files = glob.glob('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/nodos/*.csv')

  for path in files:
     dirname, filename = os.path.split(path)
     with open('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/nodos/%s' %filename) as 
     csvfile,open('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/aristas/%s' %filename,'w') as 
     output:   
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    isFirstRow = True;
    for row in csv_reader:  
         if isFirstRow:
           prevRow1 = row[1]
           isFirstRow = False
         else:        
           output.write(prevRow1 + ',' + row[1])                   
           output.write('\n')
           prevRow1 = row[1]
```

Comment: Do you know how can I count row occurrance? for example

 [WP, VBZ,10]
[ VBZ, PRP,2]
[ PRP, VB,1]

so I can use them as weight after or filter by weight over 1 for example

Comment: @SebastianCánepa Glad bo be of help. You should ask how to count row occurancet as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this:

```
out = []
prev = None
for row in list(csv_reader):
    if prev is not None: out.append(prev + "," + row[1])
    prev = row[1]
```

For a csv file with following content:

```
What, WP
makes, VBZ
them, PRP
do, VB
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> out
['WP,VBZ', 'VBZ,PRP', 'PRP,VB']
```

then you can simply do, `output.writelines(out)` to write this to file (right after the `for` loop above).